# Understanding Dask Distributed behavior with regards to DataFrame operations

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I would like to better understand how `dask.distributed` works. I have a simple csv I read into a Dask dataframe as in the below. This operation executes fine and returns some integer value representing the length of the dataframe, which is the behavior I would expect.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
gdf = dd.read_csv(filepath)
len(gdf)
# returns some int value
```

But once I introduce an instance of `Client` from `dask.distributed`, I recieve the following error:

```
distributed.utils - ERROR - 'LocalFileSystem' object has no attribute 'cwd'
```

Here is an example code block:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dd
client_db = Client(remote_addr)
gdf = dd.read_csv(filepath)
len(gdf)
# throws the above error
```

I'm confused - does `Client` "inject itself" into all Dask operations once it has been instantiated. I thought I would need to do something like `gdf = client_db.persist(gdf)` to ask that `Client` connection to manage operations on that dataframe.

Some context on what's happening here would be much appreciated! I can see from the traceback it has to do with Tornado, which is a web framework in Py that allows for web sockets, long polling, etc. I assume that it is attempting to store something... somewhere... But my familiarity drops off here.

If needed, the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../geopandas_opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 223, in f
    result[0] = yield make_coro()
  File "/.../geopandas_opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1015, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/.../geopandas_opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/.../geopandas_opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1021, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/.../geopandas_opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1156, in _gather
    traceback)
  File "/.../geopandas_opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py", line 212, in read_block_from_file
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py", line 314, in __enter__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/bytes/local.py", line 64, in open
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/bytes/local.py", line 36, in _trim_filename
AttributeError: 'LocalFileSystem' object has no attribute 'cwd'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you create a Client it registers itself as the default global scheduler.  You can avoid this behavior with the `set_as_default=` keyword

```
client = Client(..., set_as_default=False)
```

Regarding the exception you've run into I suspect that it is a version mismatch.  You might want to upgrade with either `conda` or `pip`.

```
conda install dask distributed
```

or

```
pip install dask distributed
```